# Using [Sequelize.Op.in] for json object arrays

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have a meta tag table which contains a tagId and a value.

I have an array of tagId,value objects

> Eg : [{'tagId':2, 'value':33}, {'tagId':2, 'value':34}, {'tagId':1,
> 'value':34}, etc.. ]

My metaTag table consists of a virtual column which will return the `{tagId,value}` object for each entry in table. My question is how can I select rows with each `{tagId, value}` pair in the array.

In other words, I want to be able to do something like

```
[Sequelize.Op.in]:[{'tagId':2, 'value':33}, {'tagId':2, 'value':34}]
```

This doesn't work, however.

I might not have explained this well, English isn't my first language. Please ask if you need any clarification on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use there:

```
    const myDeviceIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 29];
    const macroDevices = await MacroDevice.findAll({
    where: {
        deviceId: {
            [Op.in]: myDeviceIds,
        },
        life: {
            [Op.not]: null,
        },
        status: {
            [Op.is]: null,
        }
    },
    order: [
        ['id', 'DESC']
    ],
    limit,
    offset,
    include: [
        Macro,
        Targets,
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attain this by using Op.or. If I am not wrong you are trying
('tagId' = 2 and 'value' = 33) or ('tagId' = 2, 'value' = 34):

`where: { [Sequelize.Op.or]: [{'tagId':2, 'value':33}, {'tagId':2, 'value':34}] }`

You can add n number of values to the or array. As per your requirement.

if you want to do a in like this:
tagId in(2, 2) and value in (33, 34) then:

`where: {'tagId':[2], 'value':[33, 34]}`

You don't need the explicit Op.in for the array.